# DialogFlow: Better understanding of phone number

Tags: dialogflow-es

We are try'ng to input phone number in an Intent in DialogFlow via voice

But we have big problems with voice interaction even with different people (let me say with a good and natural English)

Using type sys.phone-number we obtain weird result as for example
Original Number as reported on DialogFlow Interface 3 8 3 3 5 7 7 6 6 4 4 4
Result number in web hook 3 8 3 3 5 7 7 6 6 4 4  (missing last number)

Another example sometimes we use double7 to indicate 77 , and the double is total missing we obtain only one 7

Same behaviour with sys any sometimes apppear a 0 near a four and so on .
Percentage of error on some number is quite high, any hint or idea on how to improve this process? As far as i understand we can't do a training on this, nor on a general entity that could contain all possible number.

It seems from my point of view a fail in the voice recognition, may be there is somewehere (Dialgoflow or google action?) some parameter we can modify to improve the success rate?

Could be a godd idea input 100 or may be 1000 correct phone number in the training phase? (i don't think this is a solution the problem is not on the phrase but only in a part of the prhase that contain the number)

Any hint is welcome!!
Thank you

Comment: you may contact support@dialogflow.com for possible bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a contact with the support center, it appears that for number with format

+39 393 XXXX XXX

i.e Telephone number with format from  E.123 [E.123 is a standards-based recommendation by the International Telecommunications Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123) , the best way to limit error is to use @sys.number-sequence, but this don't support plus sign, so we use @sys.any with some control, substituting every word before the first digit with a "+" , removing every letter and checking for validity of number with google library..

Doin'g some test it seems that using a phone with a good michrophone the % of right number recognized is the same with sys.any and sys.number.sequence (without using  the "+").
The support told us the "double3" i.e. 33 in number (or every other digit) actually is not supported (some times it seems to work fine but not too much)